# Formatting a negative TimeSpan

Tags: wpf, xaml

I need to display `TimeSpan` in `hh:mm` format. If negative, there should be a preceding `"-"`.
This is my implementation in the `.xaml`:

```
<Label>
 <Label.Content>
            <TextBlock>
                 <TextBlock.Text>
                   <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0:D2}:{1:D2}">
                         <Binding Path="MyTime.Hours" />
                         <Binding Path="MyTime.Minutes" />
                   </MultiBinding>
                </TextBlock.Text>
            </TextBlock>
 </Label.Content>
</Label>
```

Unfortunately a negative `TimeSpan` returns both, `Hours` and `Minutes` as negative values, resulting in "-07:-12" for example. However, I only need one preceding `"-"`.
Is there a way to check for negativity in the xaml code and then use a datatrigger to put the minus sign?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This custom format string with a section seperator defines sections with separate format strings for positive, negative and zero values (left out the section one for zero values).

```
<MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0:D2}:{1:0#;0#}">
    <Binding Path="MyTime.Hours"/>
    <Binding Path="MyTime.Minutes"/>
</MultiBinding>
```

Comment: This worked! Updated the answer to show the full code.

Comment: tzippy, It's [totally ok](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) to answer your own question. So feel free to mark this as an answer to help others find this easier.

Comment: Thanks @JustShadow

Comment: @tzippy Please see my answer for how to also show the minus sign for the first negative hour.

Answer (score 2):

This should work - but only when the Hours value is already `<= -1`:

```
<MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0:00}:{1:mm}">
    <Binding Path="MyTime.Hours"/>
    <Binding Path="MyTime"/>
</MultiBinding>
```

For showing the minus also for the first (negative) hour, use a Binding Converter like this:

```
public class TimeSpanConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(
        object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var ts = (TimeSpan)value;
        var result = ts.ToString(@"hh\:mm");

        return ts >= TimeSpan.Zero ? result : "-" + result;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(
        object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

with

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding MyTime, Converter={StaticResource TimeSpanConverter}}"/>
```